# How to control TargetFramework based on if netcore 2.x SDK is installed

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, .net-core

In the context of "I want to share samples with people", I would prefer no to tell people "you need netcore 2.x SDK installed to use this sample". People with only desktop .net should be able to still open the solution and run the solution.

However if a project has this

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net461;netcoreapp2.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

and does not have `netcoreapp2.0` installed they will get the following error

> The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.0.  Either target .NET Core x or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/7051 for the general ask to this problem. Currently there isn't a bullet proof solution.

One that will work for now is to check `'$(UsingMicrosoftNETSdk)' == 'true'`.  This property was added in the 2.0 SDK.  So if it exists, then it means you are using the 2.0 SDK.  If it doesn't, then it must be 1.x.

The issue with your current **hack** is that when version 3 comes some day, it will break.

Answer (score 0):

My current **hack** is to do this

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" $(BundledNETCoreAppPackageVersion.StartsWith('2.')) ">
    <TargetFrameworks>net461;netcoreapp2.0</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" ! $(BundledNETCoreAppPackageVersion.StartsWith('2.'))">
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Which seems to work, but I am hoping there is a less hack/more supported alternative

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer until you get a better answer, o it could help other community members who get the same issues.